# Spring messageSource works in JSP and not works in jUnit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC application with servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    ">

<annotation-driven validator="validator"/>

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<default-servlet-handler/>  

<!-- Apache Tails configuration -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</beans:value>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
</interceptors> 

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
            id="messageSource"
            p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/application, WEB-INF/i18n/validation_messages"
            />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
            id="localeResolver"
            p:cookieName="locale"/>

<beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.mvc" />
```

I have only two .properties files in WEB-INF/i18n/ folder:

WEB-INF/i18n/application.properties

WEB-INF/i18n/validation_messages.properties

messageSource works fine in JSP pages:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:message key="validation.User.NULL_FIRST_NAME"/>
```

and in Hibernate validator:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name="first_name")
@NotNull(message = "{validation.User.NULL_FIRST_NAME}")
@Size(max = 255, message = "{validation.User.TOO_LONG_FIRST_NAME}")
private String firstName;

//... getters and setters
}
```

But it doesn't work in jUnit test-class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JPATestConfig.class})
public class AbstractJpaTest {

@Inject
private MessageSource messageSource;

public void fillValidationMessages() {
Locale locale = null;
User_NULL_FIRST_NAME = messageSource.getMessage("validation.User.NULL_FIRST_NAME", null, locale);
}
}
```

I've try to use MessageSourceAware and different locales but every time I have the same error:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'validation.User.NULL_FIRST_NAME' for locale 'null'.
at org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(DelegatingMessageSource.java:65)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234)
at com.dominform.mvc.AbstractJpaTest.fillValidationMessages(AbstractJpaTest.java:198)
at com.dominform.mvc.jpa_tests.UserUtilTest.init(UserUtilTest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a mixture of java config and xml config?

Comment: yes. I think this is usual way to configure this type of applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass `null` value in `Locale` object. Please try to use default locale instead:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
User_NULL_FIRST_NAME = messageSource.getMessage("validation.User.NULL_FIRST_NAME", null, locale);
```

But this is not the only one reason. It seems, that paths for `spring-servlet.xml` context differ from JUnit context.

So for JUnit tests you need to change `basenames` locales into something like this:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource"
        p:basenames="file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/application, file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/validation_messages"
        />
```

For unifying Spring Servlet Config and JUnit tests I would recommend move message bundle (i.e. `i18n` folder) into `resources` maven's folder and access it with `classpath:` prefix. So in both case it will look like the following:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource"
        p:basenames="classpath:i18n/application, classpath:i18n/validation_messages"
        />
```

Comment: I already tried different variety of locales. Just tried your variant. The same story, still error.

Comment: Yes, I just check it up. It is big part of right answer. The second part - in jpaTestConfig class I connect wrong xml-config, but not servlet-context.xml. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

have you configured your messageSource in JPATestConfig.class ?
You can tray to run your test with this config.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml})"
```

Comment: yes, I add ApplicationContext(which configured from servlet-context.xml) in jpaTestConfig

Comment: try to define your basenames as classpath  p:basenames="classpath:i18n/validation_messages...

Comment: Just back to workplace. You were right, I connect wrong xml-config in jpaTestConfig. Thanks for your answer.