# Spring MVC Test with Validation JSR-303/349: Locale or accept-language does not work in testing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I am working with Spring Framework 4.3.3

I have the following situation for a `@Controller` either for `POST` or `PUT`

For example for `POST` I have the following:

```
@PostMapping(value="/save",
             consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
             produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String saveOne(@Validated @ModelAttribute Persona persona,
        BindingResult result,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

    logger.info("saveOne: {}", persona.toString());

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        logger.error("# Errors: {}", result.getErrorCount());
        logger.error("result: {}", result.toString());
        return "persona/saveOne";
    }

    personaRestController.saveOne(persona);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "process.successful");
    return "redirect:/message";
}
```

The app works how is expected, through a `Web Form` this `@PostMapping` either saves/persists the data or validates the data **and** if it is invalid the same web form is shown with the error messages for each field and based about `i18n` such as `English`, `Spanish` and `Portuguese`. It related with `JSR-439`

About Java config infrastructure configuration I have the following:

```
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
        //localeChangeInterceptor.setHttpMethods("post", "put");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean(name="localeResolver")
public LocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver(){
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("language");
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en","US"));
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
}
```

And

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

...

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptorConfig.localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
```

The problem is about `Spring MVC Test`. I have the following:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

...

@Test
public void saveOneHtmlPostInvalidMaxTest() throws Exception {

    logger.info("saveOneHtmlPostInvalidMaxTest");

    resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .locale(locale)
                .header("accept-language", locale.toString())
                .header("language", locale.toString())
                .param("id", personaInvalidMax.getId())
                .param("nombre", personaInvalidMax.getNombre())
                .param("apellido", personaInvalidMax.getApellido())
                ....
                .andDo(print());
```

**Note** observe:

```
                .locale(locale)
                .header("accept-language", locale.toString())
                .header("language", locale.toString())
```

Even when some of them have no sense, they are there because I am trying to resolve the following situation:

The validation control from the server side works how is expected *until* some point.

**First**

I can confirm through `.andDo(print())` method that `MockHttpServletRequest` prints

> Headers = {Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded],
>   accept-language=[pt_BR], language=[pt_BR]}

Observe `pt_BR`

**Second**

The `@PostMapping` that contains:

```
if(result.hasErrors()){
    logger.error("# Errors: {}", result.getErrorCount());
    logger.error("result: {}", result.toString());
    return "persona/saveOne";
}
```

Prints...

> 7370 [Test worker] ERROR PersonaSaveOneController - result:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 4 errors
>   Field error in object 'persona' on field 'id': rejected value [0];
>   codes [Size.persona.id,Size.id,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [persona.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id],3,3];
>   default message [The size for the field must be between 3 and 3]

Observe the `default message [id],3,3];
default message [The size for the field must be between 3 and 3]`

Here two problems:

- The `locale` or `accept-language` are ignored
- The error messages prints always in English

What I need is that the error data prints for example in `Portuguese` and `Spanish` according the `Locale` sent. It should returns the error messages for each field in an expected language, in this case `Portuguese`

Again, it works when I use directly the `Web Form`, but not through the Test. I am assuming that exists an internal Spring component that works through `production` and has not been defined for `Testing`

Therefore, what is need it to accomplish this approach?

BTW: With the following (see I use `classpath:`), furthermore my `.properties` file are located in `src/main/resources`

```
@Bean(name="messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasenames(...
"classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/validation/validation");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
}
```

My `@Test` methods working around with `Rest` works fine about show and returning the error message according the `Locale` or `accept-language` defined (Access to `MessageSource` happens in the server side and works fine with the previous configuration). It just fails for `non-Rest` controllers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring messageSource works in JSP and not works in jUnit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308773/spring-messagesource-works-in-jsp-and-not-works-in-junit-test)

Comment: I will say is not duplicate, the code works in production, but does not work how is expected in testing.

Comment: Just like the code in the other thread.

Comment: You are assuming is about `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`?, right? I have other test about `Rest` and works fine. The problem is the App server does not recognize the `Locale` or `accept-language` sent from the Test. All my `.properties` files are referenced through `classpath:`

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot? If so, does `spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=false` fix it? If your default language is `en` but there's no `messages_en.properties`, only a `messages.properties`, Spring will use `messages_xx.properties` if the language of your default locale is `xx`.